# Associativity in RPN

Tags: formal-languages, associativity

An operator, say $+$, is associative if $a + (b+c)$ means the same as $(a+b) + c$.

Rewriting this rule in RPN, we'd get that  $+a+bc$ means the same as $++abc$.

In this context, may I assert that an associativity, in a formal grammar sense, means that $+a+$ is equivalent to $++a$, even if $a$ is a nonterminal?

Comment: The RPN I know would write these as $abc++ $ and $ab+c+$.  The basic question still works, but with $+c+$ and $c++$.

Comment: they are equivalent except that when viewed as a FORTH program one version would use less stack

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Glad to meet a fellow Forth programmer. This is pretty much what the question is about, a kind of Forth optimizer. How can I obtain a proof that the rewrite is valid?